# Pandas: Count Higher Ranks For Current Experiment Participants In Later Experiments (Part 1)

Tags: python, pandas

#### Learning Experiments

In a series of learning experiments, I would like to count the number of participants in each experiment that improved their performance in subsequent experiments (Rank 1 is highest). In addition, I would also like to count the number of participants in each experiment that subsequently reached the top rank.

Here is a short, sanitized version of the learning experiment csv file that I have loaded into a pandas dataframe (df_learning).

| Experiment | Subject | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Alpha | 1 |
| A | Bravo | 2 |
| A | Charlie | 3 |
| A | Delta | 4 |
| A | Echo | 5 |
| B | Alpha | 1 |
| B | Charlie | 2 |
| B | Echo | 3 |
| B | Foxtrot | 4 |
| B | Golf | 5 |
| B | India | 6 |
| B | Juliet | 7 |
| C | Juliet | 1 |
| C | Bravo | 2 |
| C | Charlie | 3 |

Please advise?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a [`groupby.cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cummax.html), then [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m = df['Rank'].sub(df.groupby('Subject')['Rank'].cummax()).lt(0)

improved_rank = df.loc[m, 'Subject'].unique()
```

output: `['Charlie', 'Echo', 'Juliet']`

```
reached_top_rank = df.loc[m&df['Rank'].eq(1), 'Subject'].unique()
```

output: `['Juliet']`