# Pandas: Count Higher Ranks For Current Experiment Participants In Later Experiments (Part 2)

Tags: python, pandas

#### Learning Experiments

In a series of learning experiments, I would like to count the number of participants in each experiment that improved their performance in subsequent experiments (Rank 1 is the highest). In addition, I would also like to count the number of participants in each experiment that subsequently reached the top rank. @mozway has answered the original questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73827147/pandas-count-higher-ranks-for-current-experiment-participants-in-later-experime).

Ideally, I would also like to output the number of improved participants for each participant. For example, two participants (Charlie and Echo) from experiment 'A' improve their performances in subsequent experiments (Charlie ('B') and Echo ('B')) giving experiment 'A' a score of 2. Similarly, Juliet from experiment 'B' improves her performance in experiment 'C' giving a score of 1 to experiment 'C'.
In essence, every time there is improved performance by participants in the current experiment in subsequent experiments then it adds to the score of the current experiment.

For improved performance:

| Experiment | Score | Subjects |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | Bravo, Charlie |
| B | 1 | Juliet |
| C | 0 |  |

For top performance:

| Experiment | Score | Subjects |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | Alpha |
| B | 1 | Juliet |
| C | 0 |  |

How do I calculate these and the equivalent scores for experiments whose participants subsequently reached the 'top-rank'?

Here is a short, sanitized version of the learning experiment csv file that I have loaded into a pandas dataframe (df_learning).

| Experiment | Subject | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Alpha | 1 |
| A | Bravo | 2 |
| A | Charlie | 3 |
| A | Delta | 4 |
| A | Echo | 5 |
| B | Alpha | 1 |
| B | Charlie | 2 |
| B | Echo | 3 |
| B | Foxtrot | 4 |
| B | Golf | 5 |
| B | India | 6 |
| B | Juliet | 7 |
| C | Juliet | 1 |
| C | Bravo | 2 |
| C | Charlie | 3 |

Please advise?

Comment: It would be great to provide the explicit expected output

Comment: @mozway. For improved performances, see table after second paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in your previous question, start by getting the rows where the performance improved:

```
m = df['Rank'].sub(df.groupby('Subject')['Rank'].cummax()).lt(0)
```

Then you can computed the shifted sum per group:

```
out = (m
  .groupby(df['Experiment']).sum()
  .shift(-1, fill_value=0)
  .reset_index(name='Score')
)

  Experiment  Score
0          A      2
1          B      1
2          C      0
```

For the top ranks:

```
out = ((m&df['Rank'].eq(1))
  .groupby(df['Experiment']).sum()
  .shift(-1, fill_value=0)
  .reset_index(name='Score')
)

  Experiment  Score
0          A      0
1          B      1
2          C      0
```

Comment: Excellent. However, for the top ranks the scores should be 1,1,0!

Comment: @matekus why? Should 1->1 be considered an improvement?

Comment: Not the first output. The second output is about reaching the top rank in subsequent experiments, regardless of the rank in the current experiment.

Comment: OK, then try `df['Rank'].eq(1).groupby` instead of `((m&df['Rank'].eq(1)).groupby`